# Facebook contact sync, third party or otherwise

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

Would I be right in gathering that there is now no way to sync Facebook contacts into the Android contact system?

Apps such as Hax seem to have dissapeared or stopped working due to Facebook's API changes, so has Facebook come up with an alternative, or are we just stuck with manualy copying email addresses to to Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there is **no official way** to see your Facebook friends on your phone's contacts app.

There might be some hacks to get it done though, with some risky apps, which I strongly discourage using.

Facebook has developed an app called **Facebook Hello** as an alternative contacts app. Download it from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.phone) or [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/hello/). It is actually country-restricted in Play Store, but works if you side-load the APK file. It appears to not have been updated in a very long time and [the program is officially "deprecated".](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/07/hello-tbh-moving-on)

Another option is to use [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&hl=en). It will show all facebook contacts within itself.

Comment: This app is not available everywhere (at least not here in Germany). You can import all your local contacts to Facebook and keep them auto-synced - which of course is exactly what Facebook wanted you to do when they disabled the sync to local contacts.

Comment: @wortwart New link added. Try APK Mirror to get APK and side-load it.